# Is the annihilator of the annihilator of a space the space itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be an $m$-dimensional subspace of the $n$-dimensional vector space $U$ (of course $m\leq n$). Now, my question is if $V^{00}=(V^0)^0=V$ (where $V^0$ is the annihilator of vector space $V$)?

I just started to learn about dual spaces and annihilators and would appreciate a counterexample or proof to explain why. Thanks.

Comment: Annihilator with respect to what? A nondegenerate bilinear form, I suppose?

Comment: @rschwieb In some contexts (Axler's text e.g.) $V^0$ is defined to be a subspace of the dual $U^*$, which means no bilinear forms are required. Given the discussion of dual spaces I suspect that this is the definition used by the asker

Comment: @m **Hint:** Prove that $V \subset V^{00}$, then prove that $\dim(V^{00}) = \dim(V)$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks for that. I see how I might need to show that $V\subset V^{00}$ and that $V^{00}\subset V$ to prove the equality, but how/why are you able to replace my second condition with the condition that dimensions are the same?

Comment: @mathim1881 For finite dimensional spaces $U,V$, if $V \subset U$ and $\dim(V) = \dim(U),$ then $V = U$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Well, in that case one would refer to the natural pairing, which is a bilinear form. But either way, what good is it directing the comment to me? I was prompting the use to be clear for the benefit of responders...

Comment: @rschwieb My point was that the asker probably wasn't aware that there was anything to be clarified and had no idea what you meant by a "non-degenerate bilinear form." In other words, your request for clarification was not sufficiently clear. Analogously, there have been many introductory linear algebra questions here that have been met with the comment "over which field?" which can be (needlessly, I think) confusing and daunting for a student who has only dealt with the real/complex numbers.

Comment: @rschwieb Also, I would argue that that a comment directed towards your question provides clarification to potential responders who might have the same question

Comment: @BenGrossmann I agree the comment is helpful but it's probably more direct to address it to the user and say "did you mean perhaps <that explanation> rather than the one suggested with bilinear forms?"  It encourages a response from the OP rather than me, a random dude.

Comment: @rschwieb That's fair. I guess I was just very reluctant to start a whole conversation about "what do you mean by a bilinear form"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true. You can prove it concretely by choosing a basis $v_1, \dots v_m$ of $V$ and extending it to a basis $v_1, \dots v_n$ of $U$. If $v_1^{\ast}, \dots v_n^{\ast} \in U^{\ast}$, then you can check that the annihilator, which I'll write

$$V^{\perp} = \{ f \in U^{\ast} : \forall v \in V : f(v) = 0 \}$$

has basis given by the dual vectors $v_{m+1}^{\ast}, \dots v_n^{\ast}$. Applying this result a second time gives that $V^{\perp}$ has basis given by $v_1, \dots v_n$ so $(V^{\perp})^{\perp} = V$ as desired.

Abstractly, let $T : V \to U$ be the inclusion. $V^{\perp}$ is the kernel of the dual map $T^{\ast} : U^{\ast} \to V^{\ast}$ (exercise). Starting from the [short exact sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence#Short_exact_sequence)

$$0 \to V \xrightarrow{T} U \xrightarrow{\text{coker}(T)} U/V \to 0$$

dualizing produces the short exact sequence

$$0 \to (U/V)^{\ast} \xrightarrow{\text{ker}(T^{\ast})} U^{\ast} \xrightarrow{T^{\ast}} V^{\ast} \to 0$$

showing that $V^{\perp} \cong (U/V)^{\ast}$; in other words, the annihilator can be identified (naturally in $U$ and $V$) with the dual of the cokernel of the inclusion $T$. Dualizing a second time gives the original short exact sequence back, which gives

$$(V^{\perp})^{\perp} \cong V$$

although there's some work to do to show that all of the natural isomorphisms we just used reduce to the actual literal equality $(V^{\perp})^{\perp} = V$. This argument shows that the conclusion generalizes to finitely generated projective modules over a ring.